# performSegue not working and result crash

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I am facing weird crash when trying to call *performSegue* in storyBoard. I already configured view controller segueID and it is *UINavigation* hierarchy based viewController.I am getting the following error.

**ERROR - " has no segue with the identifier 'SEGUE_ID'"**

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I'd say this is a weird crash. This means you're trying to use a segueId that doesn't exist in the storyboard. Make sure you actually have a segue with the id `SEGUE_ID`.

Comment: Yes, SEGUE_ID is already there in Storyboard. I have used this in past. I created a new test app, still crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it was my mistake or something changed in segue connection. Earlier I used to drag the connection from **destination to the source view controller** but I feel it is not working now. It starts working when I changed the direction of connection i.e. **source to destination ViewController**.

Answer (score 2):

Check direction of your connection.

Its Destination to Source.

It should be Source to destination.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try checking

```
if segue.identifier == “SegueID”
```

In the begining of your prepare function

Comment: You mean `SEGUE_ID` to be exact, as his image shows.

Comment: @Mahgol: Not sure where I should check that but it crashes at this line `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SEGUE_ID", sender: self)`.

Comment: Did you clear the building folder and rebuild again. It's really wired. BTW, did you call it in the TestViewController?

Comment: As I said you should check it in your prepare function, I mean do “self.performSegue...”  if segue.identifier == “SEGUE_ID”

Answer (score 0):

You can check the storyBoard like this :

```
 print(self.storyboard)
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SEGUE_ID", sender: self)
```

It cannot be nil

Comment: Yes, It is not nil.

Comment: Is there any whitespace after "SEGUE_ID" by chance , like this "SEGUE_ID " in the storyboard?

Comment: No, I don't think so.